# given n random lines in a 2d plane, what's the probability for having less than k intersection points?

Tags: probability, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

In euclidean space, uniformly distributed lines (select slope and intercept uniformly from a unite square)

for example, n = 2,

when $k \leq 1$  the probability is 1. two-line at most can intersect once.

what about n = 3, 4, 5.. ?

Comment: To make an issue of *probability* one needs to assign a *probability distribution* for possible "random lines in a 2d plane", or at least assume something about the likelihood that with $n$ lines, more than two will share a common point of intersection.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder ! I’m interested in Uniform random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to choose a line in the plane uniformly at random.

I suspect that with any reasonable distribution, $n$ lines chosen at random will be in general position with probability $1$. That means that with probability $1$ every line will intersect every other at just one point, with no three way intersections. That will lead to $n(n-1)/2$ points of intersection. The probability of any other number of intersections will be $0$.

You may find interesting related reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: What about select ratio and intercept uniformly from a unit square ?

Comment: @pengyu That is one possible distribution (assuming "ratio" is what is usually called "slope"). I conjecture that  $n$ random lines will be in general position (just look at the linear equations that need to be solved). Of course many of the intersections will be outside the unit square. If you have a context in which you have reason to expect fewer intersections please [edit] the question to give us more of that context.

Comment: thanks for correcting my language! and i'm more interested in the probability distribution instead of the expected or extreme number of intersection points.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the probability distribution is boring: everything but the maximum (general position) has probability $0$.

Comment: True... thanks! And sorry my context is that my brain happen to enumerate this problem for myself. by put a few concept together, and try to see if I truly understand probability. I guess learning is boring...

Comment: No, learning isn't boring. The fact that these distributions are boring is interesting.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82622/numbers-of-intersection-points-and-lines found an interesting related problem